# How to calculate object values from 2 different APIS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, function, object

I am using 2 APIS to access food nutrition data, one is for raw food data the other one is barcode scannable for packaged foods.

The problem is that each has their own data structure, here is an example of it and path to get calories from food item.

**Api A:**
`.foodNutrients[2].value = 52`

```
foodNutrients: Array(15)[
       {nutrientId: 1087, nutrientName: "Calcium, Ca", unitName: "MG",value:0},
       {nutrientId: 1093, nutrientName: "Sodium, Na", unitName: "MG",value:0},
       {nutrientId: 1008, nutrientName: "Energy", unitName: "KCAL",value:52}
    ]
```

**Api B:**
`.nutriments["energy-kcal_100g"] = 492`

```
  nutriments = {
    calcium_100g: 0.076,
    sodium_100g: 0.196
    energy-kcal_100g: 492,
  }
```

My goal is to be able to add items from both APIS and be able to perform calculations such as counting the total calories,protein etc.

I have already set up my app to render the data based on API A, so do I somehow convert the API B data, or is there another solution?

Comment: Write a function that returns a consistent nutriment object regardless of the API. I'm not sure what you're asking exactly to be honest, there's no magical shortcut here but this isn't an unsolvable problem, not even a difficult one. Converting B into A is a valid solution but again, I don't see what the problem with that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data structure in API A lookd better, i would convert api B to use similar one. If the api B key naming is consistent, you can start by splitting from '_'

```
[{
  nutrientId: 123,
  nutrientName: "calcium",
  unitname: "100g",
  value: 0.076
}]
```

and then map it to to something like

```
[{
  nutrientId: 123,
  nutrientName: calcium,
  unitname: "kg",
  value: 0.76
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate through one while checking that they share a common name.
You can do something like this:

```
for (x in nutriments) {
    let food = foodNutrients.find(y => y.nutrientName.toLowerCase().includes(x.substr(0,4).toLowerCase()));
    if (food) { 
      food.newValue = nutriments[x]   
    }
    
}
```

this will output:

```
0: {nutrientId: 1087, nutrientName: "Calcium, Ca", unitName: "MG", value: 0, newValue: 0.076}
1: {nutrientId: 1093, nutrientName: "Sodium, Na", unitName: "MG", value: 0, newValue: 0.196}
2: {nutrientId: 1008, nutrientName: "Energy", unitName: "KCAL", value: 52, newValue: 492}
```